# How to perform keyboard actions (Page Down,Page UP) in robotframework?

Tags: robotframework

Question 1:
I have to verify keyboard actions for my web application. Any inputs on how to perform keyboard actions using robot framework would be helpful.

Question 2:
Scenario: There are 500 items in the list which can be selected by using checkbox. I have written a script to select 25 items using loop, it worked. Same script doesn't work when it is configured to 40 items. Looks like only 27 items in list are accommodated in page. Next page with items are fetched only as we scroll down or Page down is pressed in keyboard. Scroll bar/scroller is not an identifiable element, so couldn't perform scroll operation using script. So, I thought of performing two operations(Selecting checkbox and Page down) in a loop. Kindly suggest any inputs to perform this...

Answer (score 0):

`Press key` keyword is useful for your task.

Refer [here](https://github.com/robotframework/Selenium2Library/issues/498) for complete details.